# Running Java batch file on Mac

Tags: java, macos, batch-file

I am trying to run a Java application on a Mac. Currently, there is a batch file that works for Windows that looks like this:

```
java -cp lib/appframework-1.0.3.jar;lib/commons-net-3.1.jar;lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar;lib/swing-worker-1.1.jar;TimeCardApplicationOdesk.jar org.ep.gui.TimeCardApplication
```

This works fine on Windows, but running that command on a Mac outputs a bunch of gibberish (mostly "command not found" errors").

I have tried to set the class path beforehand and load the jars with the -jar switch, but I'm stumped and know nothing about Java. I'm sure there are some slight changes that need to be made to the syntax, but I'm lost.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is a good fit for Stack Overflow.  Perhaps another website in the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: I thought the same but I couldn't figure out where else it should go. Nevertheless, I got an answer very quickly and it did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all semicolons (`;`) with colons (`:`) in the command.

Multiple path entries to the `-cp` flag are separated by colons on unix systems. Following examples from these docs ([solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) and [windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)) illustrate this.

On a windows system:

```
C:> java -classpath C:\java\MyClasses;C:\java\OtherClasses ...
Note that the two paths are separated by a semicolon.
```

And on a unix like system:

```
% java -classpath /java/MyClasses:/java/OtherClasses ...
Note that the two paths are separated by a colon.
```